# svn merge theirs-full resutls are not logical when working with files with and without conflicts

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

The merge option theirs-full causes that sometimes "mine" changes **which are not in conflict** with "theirs" are discarded and sometimes not. That is confusing.

On the other hand the merge option theirs-conflict is clear: it causes that "mine" changes which are not in conflict with "theirs" are always kept. In case of a conflict "theirs" will be taken.

I don't see how theirs-full can be used safely. The logical and safe way is theirs-conflict.

**The question is** does it makes sense to change logic of theirs-full to always take "theirs" content regardless if conflict exists or not between files? As long as there is a diff between files - take "theirs".

That would make theirs-full much more useful and would make it in line with what the name of this option suggests.

Here is a bit longer explanation:

If two file versions, one from the trunk and the other from a branch, have conflicting difference then svn merge with theirs-full option will take complete version of "theirs" file. Regardless of which version is newer, merge will always take "theirs" while "mine" changes, conflicting or not,  will be discarded!

If two file versions **do not have** conflicting difference then svn merge with theirs-full option will merge changes from "theirs" into "mine" file. I will get combination of "theirs" and "mine".

This leads to unexpected merge results - files which happen to be having a conflict will be equal to "theirs" version, even non-conflicting "mine" changes will be lost. Files which happen to be without conflict will have combined content of "theirs" and "mine".

So make theirs-full to take "theirs" always, for all files which are different.

Comment: This is as statement, not a question. Do you have a question?

Comment: ok, i made my question more obvious ... so does it makes sense to change logic of theirs-full to always take "theirs" content regardless if conflict exists or not between files? As long as there is a diff between files - take "theirs".

Comment: So you'd like to have something that overwrites the target branch with the source branch. It's not really a merge, then. More like a copy but a copy that does not loose the history of the target branch.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd like to have something that overwrites the target branch with the source branch. It's not really a merge, then. More like a copy but a copy that does not loose the history of the target branch.

I think the rationale of subversion is this: if there are any modifications to the target branch not in the source branch, they should not be overwritten by a merge, the merge is only meant to bring changes in the source branch to the target branch. It probably would be a different verb than merge.

I suppose you can script it with something like this:

```
svn checkout ^/branches/target
svn checkout ^/branches/source
copy -r source/src target/src
svn commit -m 'copy files in source to target' target
```